# Create Graphs from Array values : x-y , y-z , z-x

Tags: php, arrays, path

I have a main array containing the following arrays 
(at least 50 different types) :

I'm currently programming in php but i can probably adapt the same functions in java , c# etc...

```
array('type'=>'x-y','value'=>'12');

array('type'=>'y-z','value'=>'6');

array('type'=>'y-x','value'=>'56');

array('type'=>'z-x','value'=>'19');

array('type'=>'z-y','value'=>'18');

array('type'=>'x-z','value'=>'67');

........
```

I want to create and traverse a graph for each key and run operations on them e.g :

```
x-y-z-x : 12 * 6 * 19
x-y-x : 12 * 56
x-z-x : 67 * 19
y-z-y : 6 * 18
.......
```

I have been trying to run each independently using foreach loops but it won't work for the size of dataset that i have .

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code is in php as required, you can test it as well..

```
function initData($final, $paths, $values) {
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($final);$i++) {
        $path = explode('-', $final[$i]["type"]);
        $value = $final[$i]["value"];
        array_push($paths, $path);
        array_push($values, $value);
    }
    return [$paths, $values];
}

function getFinalValue($finalPath, $paths, $values) {
    $path = explode('-', $finalPath);
    $finalValue = 1;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($path)-1;$i++) {
        $stop = $path[$i+1];
        $start = $path[$i];
        $smallPath = array($start, $stop);
        $finalValue *= getValue($smallPath, $paths, $values);
    }
    return $finalValue;
}

function getValue($smallPath, $paths, $values) {
    $value = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($paths);$i++) {
        if($smallPath[0] == $paths[$i][0])
        {
            if($smallPath[1] == $paths[$i][1]) {
                print_r($smallPath);
                echo '   ';
                $value = $values[$i];
                print_r($value);
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $value;
}



//Test
function test() {
    $a = array('type'=>'x-y','value'=>'12');
    $b = array('type'=>'y-z','value'=>'6');
    $c = array('type'=>'y-x','value'=>'56');
    $d = array('type'=>'z-x','value'=>'19');
    $e = array('type'=>'z-y','value'=>'18');
    $f = array('type'=>'x-z','value'=>'67');

    $paths = [];
    $values = [];
    $testString = 'x-y-z';
    $final = array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f);


    $data = initData($final, $paths, $values);
    $paths = $data[0];
    $values = $data[1];
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($paths);$i++) {
        print_r($paths[$i]);
        print_r($values[$i]);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';


    $finalValue = getFinalValue($testString, $paths, $values);
    echo $testString . '=' . $finalValue;


}
test();
?>
```

Comment: -  Thanks , but i'm actually trying to get all possible path from one element back to it . e.g : x-y-x , x-z-x , x-y-z-x

Comment: You can enter whatever string you wish to in the testString variable within the test function. And not only a path with 3 nodes, you can also enter a string such as 'x-y-x-z-y-x-z-x-y' and would still output you the correct answer.